# Starting mutliple orchestrations from parent orchestration and passing messages to them

Tags: biztalk, orchestration, ordered-delivery

I have a situation where a main orchestration is responsible for processing a convoy of messages. These messages belong to a set of customers, the orchestration will read the messages as they come in, and for each new customer id it finds, it will spin up a new orchestration that is responsible for processing the messages of a particular customer. I have to preserve the order of messages as they come in, so the newly created orchestrations should process the message it has and wait for additional messages from the main orchestration.

Tried different ways to tackle this, but was not able to successfuly implement it.
I would like to hear your opinions on how this could be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a set of nested convoys. While it might be possible to get that working, it's going to... well, hurt. In particular, my first worry would be maintenance: any changes to the process would be a pain in the neck to make, and, much worse, deployment would really, really suck.

Personally, I would really try to find an alternative way to implement this and avoid the convoys if possible, but that would depend a lot on your specific scenario.

A few questions, if you don't mind:

- What are your ordering requirements? For example, do you only need ordered processing for each customer on a single incoming batch, or across batches? If the latter, could you make do without the master orchestration and just force a single convoy'd instance per customer? Still not great, but would likely simplify things a lot.
- What are you failure requirements with respect to ordering? Should it completely stop processing? Save message and keep going? What about retries?
- Is ordering based purely on the arrival time of the message? Is there anything in the message that you could use to force ordering internally instead of relying purely on the arrival time?
- What does the processing of the individual messages do? Is the ordering requirement only to ensure that certain preconditions are met when a specific message is processed (for example, messages represent some tree structure that requires parents are processed before children).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a master orchestration to start up the sub-orchestrations.  I am assumin you are not talking about the master orchestration implmenting a convoy pattern.  So, if that's the case, here's what I might do.

There is a brief example [here](http://moustafarefaat.com/MoustafaPWS/singletonorchestrations.aspx) on how to implment a singleton orchestration.  This example shows you how to setup an orchestration that will only ever exist once.  All the messages going to it will be lined up in order of receipt and processed one at a time.  Your example differs in that you want to have this done by customer ID.  This is pretty simple.  Promote the customer ID in the inbound message and add it to the correlation type.  Now, there will only ever be one instance of the orchestration per customer.

The problem with singletons is this.  You have to kill them at some point or they will live forever as dehydrated orchestrations.  So, you need to have them end.  You can do this if there is a way for the last message for a given customer to signal the orchestration that it's time to die through an attribute or such.  If this is not possible, then you need to set a timer.  If no messags are received in x seconds, terminate the orch.  This is all easy to do, but it can introduce Zombies.  Zombies occur when that orchestration is in the process of being shut down when another message for that customer comes in.  this can usually be solved by tweeking the time to wait.  Regardless, it will cause the occasional Zombie.

A note fromt he field.  We've done this and it's really not a great long term solution.  We were receiving customer info updates and we had to ensure ordered processing.  We did this singleton approach and it's been problematic from the Zombie issue and the exeption issue.  If the Singleton orchestration throws an exception, it will block the processing for a all future messages for that customer.  So - handle every single possible exception.  The real solution would have been to have the far end system check the time stamps from the update messages and discard ones that were older than the last update.  We wanted to go this way, but the receiving system didn't want to do this extra work.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I ended up doing it in a different way. Still using a single orchestration to receive messages and start new orchestrations, but without the start orchestration shape. I need this main orchestration because I need to start different sub orchestrations depending on data in the messages I'm receiving.

Comment: How did you handled the ordered processing?